# Thunderbird: Reply/Reply all: a couple of formatting questions

Tags: thunderbird

I have a couple of small questions about tweaking the reply/reply all on Thunderbird 17.02 (my apologies if these are addressed in another post but I could not find it). The folks at mozillazine forum have not been able to solve this, but there are skilled TB users here who might.

This question on Ask Ubuntu comes close to several of my questions:

- [How do I make Thunderbird's reply format look like Outlook's?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173505/how-do-i-make-thunderbirds-reply-format-look-like-outlooks)

If anyone has suggestions on any of these points (or if there are add-ons to deal with them), I would greatly appreciate hearing!

#### (A) Always use the same identity when responding

I have mail from a couple of accounts forward to the one I check. As such I have created multiple identities. The mail server which I use will only allow me to use my email on its domain, so it is important that is used as the `From:` in all emails. The default seems to be that Thunderbird finds which identity is used in the original email and use that as the identity. I know I can select the correct one by hitting the pull down at the top next to the `From:` but I would like to *always* have it use the default identity so I do not have to deal with this. Is there a way to do this?

**Note:** I have thought about just having the one identity, but then when I `Reply All` it gets sent to my other email accounts which I do not want it to do.

#### (B) Suggest an add-on to format response header in particular way

I would like me response header to largely emulate the default Forward header. My goal is something like:

```
From: FromName1
Sent: Date-With-Timestamp
To: ToName1 ,..., ToNameN
Cc: CcName1 ,..., CcNameN
Subject: Subject
```

I have been using SmartTemplate 4 which comes very close to doing this, but it is unable to interweave the names and emails (instead if there are multiple To/From individuals, all names and then all emails are listed; the author confirms it is not possible to interweave the names and emails). Is there another add-on which will do this?

Note that in the Ask Ubuntu Question I linked to at the top there was a nice suggestion to have email addresses listed as html links which would be great, but the SmartTemplate code there does not work well with multiple addresses (all the emails are combined in one link: yuck!)

Answer (score 2):

**(A) Always use the same identity when responding**
I think that the only way to do this is with add-ons. There is a way to [set a default outgoing account](https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/how_do_you_set_default_account), but this default is overridden depending on the current folder selected.

An alternative is to use the [Virtual Identity add-on](https://www.absorb.it/virtual-id). This is probably overkill, and I'm not sure if there is a slimmer alternative. I don't know how I'd set it up exactly, but you might be able to set up a wildcard "to:" address, and specify an associated default "from:" address. But I'm not sure.

**(B) Suggest an add-on to format response header in particular way**
The ["Change quote and reply format" add-on](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/changequote-en.html) may do what you want. If not, there are also [additional functions](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/realborders-en.html) as stated on the linked page.

Again, I'm not 100% sure if this will help, but I thought it better to give you some possible leads.

Comment: Thanks Sparhawk. I basically have given up on this but appreciate the suggestion. (A) I tried Virtual Identity (really nice program btw!) but I could not get it to respond with same identity: maybe someone else has had more success and cane send along instructions?  (B) Change Quote seems to flaky with TB 17.0.* and at nay rate does not seem to handle the multple cc: issue I was having.

Comment: I just had another idea for A. Could you just not specify the other outgoing addresses at all in Thunderbird? Hence for each account, set "email address" to the same thing, and only change the IMAP/POP username setting? This would mean you can *never* send mail from the other addresses though. I'm not sure what other alternatives exist for B but I suspect we've exhausted them…

Answer (score 0):

For (A):

- I advise you to redirect the mailbox to the other identity (the one you want to use for the answer). It might be convenient to create a rule to put the mail with "From or Cc" to your other identity in a different directory. One mailbox, one identity.
- if this is just a problem of SMTP, you can also use the SMTP server relative to the other identity.